# opencv Mat::at and Vec3b

Tags: opencv

I'm dealing with some image completion, so I'm trying to calculate the L2 norm between two pixel at different place, and first , I tried the code below:

```
    ei += norm(img.at<Vec3b>(p1.x + i,p1.y + j) -
           img.at<Vec3b>(p2.x + i, p2.y + j));
```

only to find that it always return 0
and later, I tried the code

```
      Vec3b v1 = img.at<Vec3b>(i + p1.x, j + p1.y);
      Vec3b v2 = img.at<Vec3b>(i + p2.x, j + p2.y);
      ei += norm(v2 - v1 );
```

and this time , it works pretty fine,

so here is my question, why the first code won't work?

Comment: The arguments to `at()` are row  and column, so it should  be 

          `Vec3b v1 = img.at<Vec3b>(j + p1.y, i + p1.x);`, etc. 

and then maybe i and j should be swapped (depending on the rest of your code).

Comment: yeah ,but what I am wondering is why the first code gives an answer 0

Comment: Which is why I only posted a comment, not an answer. Are you sure those are the only lines that changed between the two cases?

Comment: Try cvNorm(arr1,arr2,CV_L2,mask). Returns double.